# Have the box above the image in HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css

I have this code: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nXbJV/1/)

I want it to look like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/aumYU/2/), but I do not want the surrounding div. I want to have the form overlay ontop of an image tag, but to look like the second link.

So how can i make the login box over the image without having the image as a background

Comment: First, adding the id to the div doesn't do what you describe.  Second, if you have something that works, why don't you want to use it?

Comment: to which div u want to add that class? How exactly do you want it. Make the fiddle of what you want.

Comment: Try remove the <div> and then uncomment the first line in that jsfiddle. And then you will see what i would like to do, but without the class

Comment: Alright see this: http://jsfiddle.net/nXbJV/5/ this is what i want.  But i do not what the #id class to hold the image url. I would like to show the image by <img in the html

Comment: why dont you do it and provide a link for it. Remove which div?

Comment: so dont use this - http://jsfiddle.net/nXbJV/10/

Comment: I have checked it in IE 8, Chrome, and Firefox. None of them have the login box over the image.

Comment: @PCasagrande I want the loginbox over the image.

Comment: I think you guys misunderstood. See this: http://jsfiddle.net/nXbJV/1/ the loginbox is under the image, because i did <img src=, See this: http://jsfiddle.net/nXbJV/5/, the loginbox is above the image, because the image is inside the class #idontwanttousethis like this: background: url(...). So how can i make the login box above the image without having the image inside the class

Comment: Any misunderstanding is from lack of clear explanation.

Answer (score 0):

In order to do what you want you must position the login box absolutely and set a z-index so that it will display properly. Here is a link: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/tJX69/1/)

Personally I prefer to use a container with a background for this sort of thing, as positioning some thing absolutely can be complicated in the rest of the layout. Either way, this link should do what you want.